# Version of Drupal is no longer supported [Using the latest 7.42 release]. After automatic update

Tags: commerce, updating

I use Drupal with Commerce Kickstarter profile installed. After automatic update from Installatron in my Direct Panel i get an error of unsupported Drupal Core version:
[image: Error from admin/reports/status]

There's no way to make update using Drush or Installatron from that state.

The only way to make it work, that I have found, is to revert to the backup before update. Can anyone help me to understand what's happening, and why  Installatron updates to the 7.42 version (7.41 -> 7.42) while Drupal Report state of 7.41 v. states that it is up-to-date?

Comment: You question is slightly vague. I suggest you edit it otherwise it might get closed.

Comment: What is "automatic update from Installatron in my Direct Panel" ?

Comment: It is an web-app automatic installer, with build in backup & update functions. It supports Drupal, Joomla, WP and more.

I have ticked an option for automatic updates with backups, and it caused that mentioned situation.

Comment: Please ask the people who support that platform @maszynka, we couldn't know what they've done to your site

Comment: you might also check /update.php to see if there are update scripts that need to be run (?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You updated Drupal core outside of updating the entire distribution. You're seeing this message because of the Distribution Update module and having upgraded outside of the distribution.

On that note, CK 2.32 uses Drupal 7.41. I will roll CK 2.33 with 7.42